# How to tag a user?

Tags: discussion

I try to tag a user in the comment to notify him of my response. Everytime I type "@{his ID}" , it does not work and it disappears. How can I tag a user correctly?

This is my post and I try to tag "Anoop Madhusoodhanan Prabha".

[How to understand the speedup in optimization report from icc compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203989/how-to-understand-the-speedup-in-optimization-report-from-icc-compiler/53713388#53713388)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Basically, tagging the poster of the person who posted the answer is pointless, because they will be notified of every comment posted regardless.